# MYSQL BETWEEN NO FILTRA

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando hacer un filtrado en mysql con BETWEEN, pero me arroja un filtrado general.

Quiero que me filtre entre fecha 01/03/2020 al 31/03/2020 pero me filtra también de 04/2020, me pueden ayudar en indentificar en que estoy erroneo?

```
SELECT * FROM `GASTOS` WHERE FECHA_U BETWEEN '01/03/2020' AND '31/03/2020'
```

Resultado:

```
FECHA_U
13/03/2020
13/03/2020
14/04/2020
14/04/2020
14/04/2020
14/04/2020
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: y el campo fecha, es de que tipo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porque el filtro que estas trantando de hacer es sobre una columna Varchar o Text, el formato DATE en mysql es con el formato yyyy-mm-dd y este no puede ser alterado, verificalo en la estructura de la tabla.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date/

Comment: Pero ¿y si no puede cambiar el tipo de dato, cómo debería hacer la consulta?

Comment: y cual seria la solucion?

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre es cargar los datos a otra tabla haciendo la conversión a travez de php o MySQL y luego de eso puedes hacer el BETWEEN.

Comment: en php puedes usar $fecha="'".date("Ymd", strtotime($fecha))."'";

Comment: por favor mira [answer].. esta respuesta es simplemente un comentario...

Answer (score 0):

La solución esta en el formato de la columna de FECHA_U, se tiene en tipo de datos varchar cuando debe estar en DATE, actualice esa parte y se pudo hacer el filtrado sin problema.

Comment: Esa era la solución de base.